# react-ultimate-pagination how to set bootstrap 3 theme

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I followed the es6 setup given here https://codesandbox.io/s/01n2y3r4nl.How do I set bootstrap3 theme?

```
import { createUltimatePagination } from "react-ultimate-pagination";
```

Demo page here Uses below code https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wQoXOG.

```
const UltimatePagination = reactUltimatePaginationBootstrap3.default;
```

With es6 syntax what is reactUltimatePaginationBootstrap3?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps someone.

I installed bootstrap3 component and later imported the component as below.

```
npm install react-ultimate-pagination-bootstrap-3 --save

import UltimatePaginationBootstrap3 from 'react-ultimate-pagination-bootstrap-3';

<UltimatePaginationBootstrap3
   totalPages={5}
   currentPage={this.state.page}
   onChange={this.onPageChange}
 />
```